# "Attempt to send to unsubscribed recipient"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

I wanted to ask if when I try to send to a number that opted out, it returns the "Attempt to send to unsubscribed recipient" error. Does it count in the message queue? Because we only have so much message throughput meaning you can only send so many messages at one time.

If it does I think I should probably add something in the code to log people that unsubscribed so that way I don't attempt to send them messages. Does anyone know whats the best way to do this? I use Javascript. Thank you so much

Currently I'm sending messages to people that opted out but I'm not sure if that's causing me problems or if I should just leave it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.